# Extract the object from the image by cutting the edges in C#

Tags: c#, crop

I am trying to crop the object from its background on an image using AForge.net. I have detect the edges of the object using cannyEegeDetector, but I don's know how to crop it using the detected edges. 
Do you have any ideas to crop the object from the background?

Answer (score -1):

I don't know anything about the data structure that CannyEdgeDetector returns, but you probably want to treat it with an algorithm similar to contour filling in the selected area (kinda like the fill bucket in MS Paint). On each row of the images pixels, start from the left side of the image scanning right, and each time you cross a boundary, you toggle whether it's in the "fill area". Pixels in the fill area are preserved, ones outside of it are cropped. Hope that helps!

Comment: He said that he already had edge information. Please read the question more carefully.

Comment: So you are satisfied with your answer?

Comment: Are you not? If there's something I'm missing, please inform me, and I'll improve the answer. That wasn't me that down voted your comment btw (I don't have enough rep!)

Comment: OK, I'll wait some time. If OP likes your answer I'll remove the downvote, fair enough? (FYI: comments can not be downvoted. it is included in my comment saying I am the one who downvoted the answer)

Comment: Thank you Brent, but I am not quite interesting in how the algorithm works, I am looking for some codes to apply on the image so that I could crop it following the edges I ve detected.

Comment: btw, I am now using the blob function in the C# instead which detect the biggest blob in the image( which I think it includes), then crop the image by using the rectangle area from the blob. The result is good but I think will be better, if there are other codes to crop the object following its curve to make it more explicit.